# Changing a global variable in callback function that is looped in C

Tags: c, for-loop, global-variables

This function will be in a constant loop.  When a button is pressed it needs to check if a condition is true or not, and then change that same condition.  (On/Off Button).

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to use a variable that I can change globally each time so that it remains so until the next button push.

I'm a noob in C so I wouldn't be surprised if this is very simple and I'm just not seeing it.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for being so Vague before:

the following is only returning values for false:

```
#define RELAY  1
#define BUTTON 0

//starts in off position
bool isOn = false ;

void waitButton (void)
{
  fflush (stdout) ;
  //Button is Pressed
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == 1)
  {
    printf ("Button pushed\n") ;
    //if it's off, turn it on
    if (isOn = false)
    {
      digitalWrite (RELAY, LOW) ;
      static bool isOn = true ;
      printf("Turned off\n") ;
    }
    //if it's on turn it off
    if (isOn = true)
    {
      digitalWrite (RELAY, HIGH) ;
      static bool isOn = false ;
      printf("Turned On\n") ;
    }
    //delay for release of button so it does not trigger twice in a row
    delay(3000) ;
  } else 
  //Button is not pressed keep going through loop
  {

    printf("Waiting for Button\n") ;
    delay(200) ;
  }

}

int main (void)
{
  setup() ;
  for (;;)
  {
    funcA () ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. I assume you know how to declare and use a global variable (though it's not clear from what you have written). So what exactly is your question? Are you asking how to set that global variable in response to a button press?

Comment: You made it a difficult riddle.

Comment: Simply declare one single `static bool isOn` inside the function.

Comment: That doesn't work, because it basically resets isOn to true everytime it starts the function again in the for loop.

Comment: In another language I would normally have a global variable passed to this callback function during the for loop; that would be changed each time from the output of the function. I don't know how to do that in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below runs. Your code was nearly good enough to run.
Your work is not finished but this runs and gives you a starting point.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// you said global variables , here they are
int button1 = 0;
int button2 = 0;
int condition1 = 0;
int condition2 = 0;
// end global variables

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int setup(  )
{
  // whatever setup you need
}

funcA(  )
{
  if ( button1 )
  {
    printf( "\nYou pressed button1" );
    // add code here to do something
  }
  if ( button2 )
  {
    if ( condition2 == TRUE )   // double = sign is very important here
    {
      condition2 = FALSE;   // change condition2 to false
      printf( "\nYou pressed button2 and condition2 is now 0" );
    }
    else
    {
      condition2 = TRUE;    //change condition2 to true
      printf( "\nYou pressed button2 and condition2 is now 1" );
    }
//    delay(500) ;
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int i = 0;
  setup(  );

  for ( i; i < 100; i++ )   // lets loop 100 times for now
  {
    button1 = 1;
    button2 = 0;
    funcA(  );
    button1 = 0;
    button2 = 1;
    funcA(  );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, BobRun.  But my dilemma is that I am using the same button; so the condition that triggers whatever happens when the button is pushed in the loop also has to flip the value of the condition that triggers it.  this way it will do the opposite of what is done the first time. (on/off)

Comment: Please read the code I posted, I use only one button, the other button1 is there to let you expand the code if needed. Simply remove button1 and associated loop.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough.  That does work.  I'm assuming that changing the value of the button in the for loop is for testing purposes.  This was a good answer;  My issues were with my syntax and setting variables.

Comment: OK , if it is a good answer then please tick it as answered, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the variable `condition2` as a global variable and change it in the function `funcA`.

```
bool condition2 = true;
funcA()
{
 // your code
}
```

Or you can declare `condition2` as a `static` variable in `funcA`. Then the state can be saved in the loop. See the [wiki page](https://en.wiki2.org/wiki/Static_%28keyword%29) for detail if you are not familiar with the `static` keyword.

```
funcA()
{
 static bool condition2 = true;
 // your code
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an embedded system? It yes, If the button is going to be pressed at any time, the best way to do it is by means of interrupts. Calling Delay routines might cause a key event to be missed.

If it is just a C console program that you are writing, then still I would recommend not to delay the way you have done in the code.

If I have understand your use-case correctly, You need a variable that changes its state on every key press, and memorizes it till the next key press event.

```
unsigned int gU32KeyState = CLEAR; //SET and CLEAR can be macros, defined to 1 and 0 respectively.

/* 
 * gU32KeyState shall be updated function or ISR that get the key event.
 * On a simple note, you can toggle gU32KeyState by simply EX-ORing it with 1:
 * as in -- gU32KeyState ^= 1;
 * Additionally, extern the variable if it is supposed to be used with some other source file too: 
 * as in -- extern unsigned int gU32KeyState;
 */

void funcA(void)
{
  //button pressed?
  if(SET == gU32KeyState)
  {
    if(TRUE == condition2)
    {
      //change condition2 to false
      condition2 = FALSE; //TRUE and FALSE can be macros, defined to 1 and 0 respectively.
    }
    else
    {
      //change condition2 to true
      condition2 = TRUE;
    }
    delay(500) ; //Can't quite comprehend why a delay is needed
  }
  else
  {
    delay(500) ; //Can't quite comprehend why a delay is needed
  }
}
```

I don't have any idea about what condition2 is. To make a logic understandable I have simply treated it as just another variable of the data type of your preference. Also, supposed if the key is pressed, the variable is set, the first `if` condition in `funcA()` would be evaluated as true as long as the button is not pressed again. But, condition2 will keep on toggling all the time when first `if` is evaluated true. Does that need a thought again?

Obviously, the code snippet that I have given can't be compiled right away.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question so I an guessing,
Use
 if(condition2==true) 
instead of
if(condition2=true), see is it working or not

Answer (score 0):

**Figured it out**

syntax errors galore.

```
int ISON = 0 ;

waitButton ()
{
  fflush (stdout) ;
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == 1)
  {
    printf ("Button pushed\n") ;
    if (ISON == 1)
    {
      digitalWrite (RELAY, LOW) ;
      ISON = 0 ;
      printf("Turned off\n") ;
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite (RELAY, HIGH) ;
      ISON = 1 ;
      printf("Turned On\n") ;
    }
    delay(3000) ;
  } else {
    printf("Waiting for Button\n") ;
    delay(200) ;
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  setup () ;
  for (;;)
  {
    waitButton   () ;
  }
}
```